# Single UDP socket multiple clients processing data in another thread

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

This is for Linux written in C.

I have a single UDP socket in a while loop receiving datagrams as fast as they come in. Multiple clients (6) are using the same UDP port, and I use select() to tell if the socket is readable.

I want to keep the UDP receiving in its own thread so I can remove the datagrams as fast as possible. My question is, how can I send the data received into another processing thread safely? Do I need a mutex?

I was looking into mq_send() and mq_receive(), but I think this would be overkill?

Comment: If you are only receiving datagrams, you don't need select(), just recvfrom().  If you want to push the datagrams off  to another thread for processing, then I suggest that you read the datagrams into a malloced buffer, (maybe [64k], depends on your data), and then, after reading, push the buffer address off onto a producer-consumer queue(of which there are numerous examples around that use condvars or semaphores) and malloc another buffer for the next datagram.  Don't forget to free the 'used' buffers in the processing thread when done:)

Comment: I'm receiving in one thread and sending datagrams in another

Comment: I want to avoid malloc() because it is an embedded system with uClinux